# Increment decrement jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-mc-red" id="myTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Availability</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                                <th>Subtotal</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $subtotal = 0; foreach($cart_details as $cart) { ?>
                                <form action="<?php echo base_url('cart/updateCart'); ?>" method="post">
                                <tr>
                                    <input type="text" name="rowId[]" value="<?php echo $cart['rowid']; ?>" style="display: none;">
                                    <td data-title="Product" class="vertical_text">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $cart['options']['image_url']; ?>" class="img-responsive" style="height: 75px;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Description" class="vertical_text">
                                        <h5><?php echo $cart['name'] ?></h5>
                                        <p>
                                            <?php echo $cart['options']['desc']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <input type="text" name="pincode[]" value="<?php echo $cart['options']['desc']; ?>" style="display: none;">
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Availability" class="vertical_text">
                                        Stock Available
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Price" class="vertical_text">
                                        <span class="p_price"><?php echo $cart['price']; ?></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Qty" class="vertical_text quantity">
                                       <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button> 
                    
                                        <input class="cart-input" type="text" name="qty[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart['qty']; ?>">
                                         <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Subtotal" class="vertical_text">
                                        <span class="sub_total_amt"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo number_format($cart['subtotal'], 2); ?></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td data-title="Action" class="vertical_text">
                                        <button class="button remove" onclick="delete_cart_product('<?php echo $cart['rowid']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $subtotal = $subtotal+$cart['subtotal']; } ?>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

this is my table with foreach loop. im using codeigniter and bootstrap.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var quantitiy=0;
    $('.quantity-right-plus').click(function(e){
    
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());//10
    
    // If is not undefined
        
        $('#quantity').val(quantity + 1);

      
        // Increment
    
});

 $('.quantity-left-minus').click(function(e){
    // Stop acting like a button
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the field name
    var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    
    // If is not undefined
  
        // Increment
        if(quantity>1){
        $('#quantity').val(quantity - 1);
        }
});

});
```

here is my jquery code.

and my problem is in this code.

```
    <td data-title="Qty" class="vertical_text quantity">
        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button> 
        <input class="cart-input" type="text" name="qty[]" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $cart['qty']; ?>">
       <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
       </button>
</td>
```

Whenever foreach loop generate second or third row the id of input #quantity is same and when I'm clicking to second or third row (+) button or (-) button the value of first row input incrementing or decrementing.

It's happening because of same id `#quantity`. I just wanted when I'm click second row (+)button or (-)button the value of second input increment or decrement. Someone please help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$('#quantity').val()` has a value before incrementing it?

Comment: if there is two row in my table first row working properly but when im click on second row (+)button or (-)button the value of first row input increamented and decreamented.

Comment: yes $('#quantity').val() its has value maybe 1 or 2 or more

Comment: You aren't showing us the whole code. Where's the object with the "quantity" id? How is it initially assigned a value? I think some code may be resetting it to 1 somewhere. Nothing in the jQuery shown is limiting it to 2 (although you should have a decrement limit of 0 or 1).

Comment: here is my all jquery

Comment: function delete_cart_product(cartId)
                {
                    if(confirm("Are you sure, You want to delete?"))
                    {
                        location.href="<?php echo base_url("cart/deleteCart"); ?>/"+cartId;
                        document.getElementById("quantity").value = "0";
                        window.location = "http://www.phoolmarket.com/cart/view.php";
                    }
                }

Comment: function numberWithCommas(x) {
                    x = x.toString();
                    var pattern = /(-?\d+)(\d{3})/;
                    while (pattern.test(x))
                        x = x.replace(pattern, "$1,$2");
                    return x;
                }

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".cart-input").keyup(function() {
                        var qty = $(this).val();
                        var price = $(this).parent().parent().find(".p_price").text();
                        var subTotal = numberWithCommas(parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(qty));
                        $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_total_amt").html("<i class='fa fa-inr'></i> " + subTotal);
                    });
                });

Comment: I see you added `id="quantity"`. IDs must be unique. Use `$(".cart-input")` instead and get rid of `id="quantity"`. It's not needed if you use  `.cart-input` and increment/decrement its value.

Comment: Do NOT dump code into comments!  Please use the `edit` link under your OP and put it where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same `id` for multiple elements on the same page. If you really need to identify each field by `id`, you need to make sure they're unique, e.g. you can append a counter to it: `quantity_1`, `quantity_2`, etc.

For your case, a better solution would be to drop the `id` attribute from the field altogether and find an alternative way to locate the input field in your increment/decrement script. My solution below locates the field with class `cart-input` within the same table cell as the button that was clicked.

**HTML/PHP**

```
<input class="cart-input" type="text" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $cart['qty']; ?>">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.quantity-right-plus').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $field = $(this).closest('td').find('.cart-input');
    var quantity = parseInt($field.val(), 10);

    $field.val(quantity + 1);
});
```

Also make sure you always specify the radix argument on `parseInt()` to avoid nasty bugs.